# mysql foreach setting dynamic ID class and value

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table setup. I'm struggling to figure out how to set the select to make my foreach loop through the results and display the proper pest_counts and pest_names with each card_id. I'm positioning the the card_id on a map using the left_x and top_y but I want only the pest_count and pest_name to appear by each card_id. I can get all or one of the counts to appear with each card_ id but I can't get each of the pest_counts and pest_names that is associated with that card_id.
Here's my table

```
pest_name   pest_count  card_id   card_type top_y   left_x   scout_date
Aphids      2              1       yellcard  652    703   3/13/2014 15:59:54
Thrips      4              1       yellcard  652    703   3/13/2014 15:59:54
Thrips      2              2       bluecard  754    707   3/13/2014 15:59:54
Thrips      1              3       yellcard  531    616   3/13/2014 15:59:54
Thrips      1              5       yellcard   80    613   3/13/2014 15:59:54
```

Here's what I want in the end for each pest_name and pest_count at each card.
This would be card_id 1

```
   2 Aphids
   4 Thrips
```

Here's one of many selects I've tried.

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT card_id,card_type,top_y,left_x,pest_count,pest_name,scout_date FROM scout_logpestnum WHERE scout_date ='2014-03-13 15:59:54' GROUP BY card_id");
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Here's the html.

```
<?php
 foreach($result as $obj) {
?>
<div id="input<?= htmlspecialchars($obj['card_id']) ?><?= htmlspecialchars($obj['pest_name']) ?>" class="input stickyinput"><?= htmlspecialchars($obj['pest_count']) ?></div>

 <div class="pestnameholder">
<?php
echo'<div class="pestname '.$obj['pest_name'].'">'.$obj['pest_name'].'</div>' ;
echo '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: Your desired end result is missing.

Comment: I'm still interested in getting this to work. The code below shows the <br/> as text along with the pest_name and pest_count. So I get 2 Aphids<br/>4 Thrips actually showing on the page. The <br/> is viable to the user. Was wondering if a JOIN would accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm going with this for now until I can figure how to include the dynamic class so I can show and hide. group_concat(concat(pest_count,' ',pest_name) SEPARATOR 0x1D)

Comment: I thought the above worked but after increasing the width of the div the results were on one line. I've tried <br>, \n and others but everything actually shows on the page and is in the source code when I look at it in FX. What would cause this issue? So for example on my actual page I see 2 Aphids<br/> 4 Thrips<br/>. The <br/> isn't hidden as source code like what I want so it actually shows as the final result to the user.

Comment: I found the issue You can't use <?= htmlspecialchars($obj['pests']) ?> you have to use <?php echo $obj['pests'];?> Thanks for your thoughts. I will stay with this until I find a way to place them within dynamic classes.

Comment: After much poking and prodding here's if you want to set a div and add a class being assigned by the value of a column field in your table through the concat. group_concat(concat(' <div class=',pest_name,'>',pest_count,' ',pest_name,'</div>') SEPARATOR ' ') You need the SEPARATOR ' ' becuase it will defualt with a , if you don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `group_concat` and `concat` for your pest names and counts, and then group by all the other attributes. This allows you to have a single label for pest_name and pest_count:

```
select
  group_concat(concat(pest_count,' ',pest_name) separator '<br/>') pests,
  card_id,
  card_type,
  top_y,
  left_x,
  scout_date
from scout_logpestnum
group by
  card_id,
  card_type,
  top_y,
  left_x,
  scout_date
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dad13/10

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have never used that function. I think that will work fine but how do you get the (2)Aphids and (4)Thrips to be stacked on top of each other instead of one line?

Comment: After further thought I really need those labels with their values in a separate div because I want to be able to hide labels and their values based on their class.

Comment: You could put the html in the `pests` string. Try `group_concat(concat(pest_name,' (',pest_count,')<br/>'))` to add a line break between pests, or `group_concat(concat('<div class="',YourClassValue,'">',pest_name,' (',pest_count,')</div>'))` to put each label in a separate `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks. That's not going to work because I need the class set dynamically through the foreach loop the way it is in my html.

Comment: No way you can pull YourClassValue from the database? What determines the class?

Comment: Here's the name being assigned a class from the foreach loop. '<div class="pestname '.$obj['pest_name'].'">'.$obj['pest_name'].'</div>' I want to be able to hide the name and its associated value.

Comment: I wonder if I could use another method to get this done. I can't figure out why I can't get the values without using the concat.

Comment: So you want to have separate div classes for each pest name, but you want multiple pest names with the same card_id to be displayed within the same div? I'm not sure that is logically possible. Could you show/hide by passing a Where to your sql select?

Comment: Yes I have each pest_name and pest_count inside a div that is set by the card_id. I was showing and hiding using JQuery but I guess I could do it with ajax so the where $varaible could be set.

Comment: How about using this type of loop to count card_id's from another select array and use that to grab the proper pest_count and pest_name for each card_id. for ($i=0; $i < count($card_ids); $i++ ) {// do select stuff here. }

Comment: I tried this group_concat(concat(pest_name,' (',pest_count,')<br/>'))  but it echos the <br> in with the name and count.

Comment: To get the `<br/>` between each card_id grouping, set the `separator` to `'<br/>'`: `group_concat(concat(pest_name,' (',pest_count,')') separator '<br/>')` http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dad13/9

Comment: I tried that earlier because it wasn't working and that still shows the <br/> in the result. I see it in your fiddle with FX.

Comment: Yes, I thought you wanted the <br/> in the result to put the pests on separate lines. What result are you looking for?

Comment: I finally figured it out and came up with the ability to set the class through adding the pest_name field as the class in the concat. I changed your posted code to reflect that change. Thanks for the pointers. group_concat(concat(' <div class=',pest_name,'>',pest_count,' ',pest_name,'</div>') SEPARATOR ' ')